# Improving the IO of python code for testing machines

Tags: python

I was doing some practice problems in [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com). There is this problem called [Ambiguous permutations](http://www.codechef.com/problems/PERMUT2/):

My Solution to this was:

```
while 1:
   cnt = int(raw_input())
   if cnt == 0:
      break
  vals = [int(u) for u in raw_input().split(' ')]
  valr = []
  for i in range(cnt):
    valr.append(vals.index(i+1)+1)
  if vals == valr:
    print 'ambiguous'
  else:
    print 'not ambiguous'
```

When I checked it out in [Trypython.org](http://www.trypython.org), it worked as expected. But when I submitted the solution in Codechef, it timed out.

My question is this. Is there anything wrong (/could be improved) with the code, or is there any specific way to handle sysin and outputs for testing machines?

[EDIT]
The accepted solution provided some great suggestions, and I rethought the code logic and modified the code accordingly. The code now runs within time, although it fails with wrong answer (not able to replicate the wrong answer in my test cases though). Thanks for the advice.

```
import sys
def ambigcheck(lis):
   amb = 'ambiguous'
   for i in range(1,len(lis)+1):
       if lis[lis[i-1]-1] != i:
          amb = 'not ambiguous'
          break
   return amb 
while 1:
   cnt = int(sys.stdin.readline())
   if cnt == 0:
       break
   vals = [int(u) for u in sys.stdin.readline().split(' ')]
   sys.stdout.write(ambigcheck(vals))
```

Comment: This probably belongs on codereview

Comment: One suggestion: IO is computationally expensive, as are `while` and `for` loops. You should use `map()` and generator expressions as much as possible. See if you can separate the IO from the main body of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `raw_input`. Use `sys.stdin`: as an iterator, or `read()` it once. And use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`. Try to use it only once: precalculate the whole output and write it to screen after.

This will give you the fastest I/O in Python.

More tips:

- you don't need to construct a new permutation, you can just check if elements in original permutation have proper indexes
- you don't need to do full check, if at least one element doesn't have proper index, permutation is not ambiguous
- avoid `.index()` method, check by index, not by value
- you can handle input even more effectively by reading only odd lines with `itertools.islice` (you don't need number of items in Python)